# Matching identical objects in two models

Tags: mesh, collections

I have two separate collections:[image]
each of these collections both contain an identical object (blue cone). In reality, it is much more complex than this example and the shared object could be like in the middle of hundreds of other objects. How can I select the shared object then merge the shape into something like this:

[image]

Found this tool which does exactly what I want but I am looking for a free way to do it that might be a little more work but still does the same job without having to manually line it up: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcGM76dwF_s

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. set the origins of these identical objects to geometry -> In object mode choose the first object in the top menu, select Object->Set Origin->Origin to Geometry (do this for both objects)
2. With both object selected press "Ctrl"+"a" ->"All transforms" -- just in case reset the transforms.
3. select the object which you want to remains in the current position
4. press "Shift"+S -> select "Cursor to selected"
5. select the second object
   6)press "Shift"+S -> select "Selection to cursor"
   The second object will match the first.